# What versions of pdf does liferay support?

Tags: pdf, liferay-6, versions

I have added a few pdf files to the documents and media portlet, but only a few are showing the thumbnails and few are not.

I was wondering is it because of the versions of PDF.

Can somebody suggest me what versions of pdf's does liferay support?

Comment: I don't understand you question.
Portable Document Format (PDF) is a file format used to present documents in a manner independent of application software, hardware and operating systems.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs either when you uploaded the PDF files or when you see the portlet with the list of PDFs? I have seen certain Liferay versions generating errors in the logs if the PDF files were corrupt. The errors were resolved when the PDF files were fixed and saved properly and uploaded again. Our error - Error: Could not parse predefined CMAP file for 'Adobe--UCS2'.This is what we got-"A similar error is reported by PDFBox on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1598, but specifies that the pdf is corrupt and even Adobe Acrobat doesn't open those files correctly."

Comment: I guess, this is not the issue with PDF's. Please check the size of PDF. Sometimes if the size is big, Liferay's PDF viewer takes time to load the PDF.